# Formatting is lost after publishing the content

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) with [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) in my Drupal 7 website. I observed that the copied content looks similar in editor and even preview also looks nice. But all the formatting is lost after publishing the content.

To debug the issue, I checked the HTML and found that the actual style is present in the code. Please see the below screenshot-[image: Content after publishing]

I noticed that after disabling the color property of `background` for `td` element, the original color appears. Please see the below screenshot-
[image]

Please suggest any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your input format is a "filtered HTML"? If I'm not in wrong it removes a lot of attributes: try to change it to "Full HTML" and verify the behaviour...

Comment: I am using "Full HTML". I can see the formatting in "Preview" but after saving, the formatting is lost. Am I missing something? or is it not configured properly?

Comment: Check what "Full HTML" text format is configured to do. If it is configured similar to the default "Filtered HTML" text format, then that is the cause. Alternatively you can also install an input filter module called WYSIWYG FIlter (the name is deceptive) which is a more robust input filter for properties and attributes allowing to whitelist those that are necessary.

Comment: @mradcliffe: I am using the default configuration of "Full HTML". Please see the screenshot [here](https://db.tt/F11E1L5S)

Comment: @RaviJoshi if you edit the content (after saving) that attribute is still present in the source?

Comment: @PierpaoloCira: Yes. I just tired editing it. The page opened in "Full HTML" editor view. I clicked on "Show HTML" and found the original HTML attributes in it. After saving it, the formatting is lost again. Somehow the global css is overwriting it.